# Como exibir múltiplos conteúdos no @yield do sistema de template Blade do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Bem, possuo um site em andamento na linguagem de programação do Laravel. Na minha `welcome.blade.php` criei uma `@yield` denominada `sides`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a criação dessa `yield`, criei as pastas no diretório do meu laravel:
`resources/views/sides/homepage` e coloquei meus arquivos separados em três `.php`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a criação desses arquivos adicionei a seguinte linha de comando:

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('sider')
    meu conteúdo
@stop
```

em cada um deles, agora gostaria de saber como chamar os três arquivos separadamente dentro de uma única `yield` ao entrar na página.

Comment: É uma mistura de `sides` e `sider` que até fiquei tonto, mas, assim, se cada arquivo é um template que estende de `welcome`, como você deseja exibir 3 layouts diferentes? Parece-me que nem deveria ser `yield`/`section` aí; um `include` talvez?

Comment: Bem, eu gostaria de exibir separadamente, por que ao mudar de página não ficará exibindo o mesmo menu lateral sempre, irá alterar de acordo com minhas necessidades. Então desejo exemplo: `Página Inicial - 2 menus`, subpáginas `3 menus diferentes dos das páginas inicial` mais ou menos nesse sentido sabe ...

Comment: Então seu código já deveria fazer isso; qual é o problema?

Comment: Ai que está, por está separado desse jeito, quando eu chamo o `@yield` ele me pedi para chamar no `route/web.php` ai não sei criar essa chamada dentro da `view`, pois só consigo chamar um `view` por vez, exemplo: `return view('sides/homepage/requests')` sendo que desejo chamar mais ou menos assim: `return view('sides/homepage/requests', 'sides/homepage/support')` e assim por diante

Comment: Mas você quer chamar uma por vez, pois quer exibir separadamente, não? Está cada vez ficando mais confuso.

Comment: Calma deixa eu ver um jeito que consiga te explicar sem confundi, calma ...

Comment: Pronto, acho que assim fica melhor de você entender, olhe o contorno: https://imgur.com/a/qfrfxKg

Comment: Exatamente. Se cada página é carregada de forma separada, basta chamar a respectiva view.

Comment: Entendi ... Grato!